# Can I use my @icloud.com email address for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, macosx

I'm thinking about switching from OS X to Ubuntu, and I want to know if I can use my iCloud email address, or if I'll have to make a new one.

Comment: Does this service supports POP/IMAP?

Comment: Even if thunderbird does not support it, I assume it has a web interface, and so could still be usable on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, as The Man says. Since icloud.com [supports both POP3 and IMAP](http://smtp-pop3.com/icloud-pop3-settings.html), you can configure Thunderbird to pick up mail from the icloud.com servers, and send through it.

This suggests deciding which you wish to use, [POP3 or IMAP](http://webhostinginformation.net/imap-explained/). IMAP leaves the messages on the icloud.com servers until you delete them, whereas when you pick up mail using POP3, they are removed from icloud.com's servers.